# My simple oracle query takes too long to complete

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, time, query-optimization

I'm trying to run the following `SQL` statement that is taking too long to finish in Oracle.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT timestamp from data
 WHERE (timestamp IN 
            (SELECT MIN (timestamp) FROM data
             WHERE (( TIMESTAMP BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2))
```

If anyone can help with optimising this query I would be very grateful.

Comment: What optimizations have you considered already?  Do you need help with choosing between alternatives?

Comment: The query is not syntactically correct.  You are missing a closing parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to speed your query is an index on `timestamp`:

```
create index data_timestamp on data(timestamp);
```

If you are expecting only one result, you can also do:

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp)
FROM data
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2
```

I'm not sure why you would want to output the timestamp multiple times.